# checkValidity() and reportValidity() is not working in the for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi step form and I want to add HTML 5 form Validation by JavaScript on current step. And I'm using checkValidity() and reportValidity() in for loop in my code but it only works on last fields of current step. Below are the my form code and JavaScript code please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
      // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      x[n].style.display = "block";
      //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
      if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
      }
      if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").name = "signup";
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").type = "submit";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").name = "";
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").type = "button";
      }
      //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
      fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
      // This function will figure out which tab to display
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
      if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
      // Hide the current tab:
      x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
      // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
      currentTab = currentTab + n;
      // if you have reached the end of the form...
      if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
      }
      // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
      showTab(currentTab);
    }

    // VALIDATION CHECK HERE
    function validateForm() {
      // This function deals with validation of the form fields
      var x, y, i, valid = true;
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
      y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
      // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
      for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

        if(y[i].checkValidity()) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            y[i].reportValidity();
            valid = false;
        }

      }

      // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
      if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
      }
      return valid; // return the valid status
     }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
      // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
      var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
      x[n].className += " active";
    }
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,30}" required="required"></p>
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,30}" required="required"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input type="email" placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email" required="required"></p>
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone" pattern="[6-9][0-9]{9}" required="required"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd" required="required"></p>
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn" required="required"></p>
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy" required="required"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input type="text" placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname" required="required"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password" required="required"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#regForm {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 70%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;  
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}

/* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
input.invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}

/* Hide all steps by default: */
.tab {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Raleway;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#prevBtn {
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

/* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
.step {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
  border: none;  
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
.step.finish {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you've got an issue around your "if(y[i].checkValidity()) { return true;}" if this hits, the return statement will not only exit the loop but also the function and will never hit your if(valid){...}

Comment: ok, what should be there please let me know

Comment: OK, Now resolve the issue thank you

Comment: if(y[i].checkValidity()) {
   valid = true;
  }
  else {
   y[i].reportValidity();
   valid = false;
   return false;
  }