# How can I change button type from, button to submit button at the last step in multi step form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, button

I have a multi-step form which contains three steps in which I have the two buttons next button and previous button to move between steps of the form. The button type of the next button is *button*. But, in the case of next button, at the last step of the form I want to have the button type as *submit* and not *button*.
Below is the code of html which contains the next button attribute-

```
<button style="height:50px;width:100px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" button type="button"
                    id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
```

And this is the javascript code which contains next function-

```
if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
```

I want to change the next-button type to *submit* button at the last step of multi-step form.
The above js code converts the text in the button from Next to Submit, but it does not change it's type from button to submit button. Please give me a solution for this problem.

Thank you.

I tried creating another buttton and inserting in the js code mentioned above in the place of id (nextBtn)
as submit button and making it's button type as submit button, but it starts appearing at the first step of the form along with the next button. Which would be  a lot more confusing for a user to fill the form.

Here is the complete javascript code of the multi-step form-

```js
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
  // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
  if (n == 0) {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
  }
  if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
    const but = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
const last = n == (x.length - 1)
but.textContent = last ? "Submit" : "Next";
but.type = last ? "submit" : "button";  
if (last) but.onclick=null; // I assume this is a good idea too
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }
  // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
  fixStepIndicator(n)
}


function nextPrev(n) {
  // This function will figure out which tab to display
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
  if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
  // Hide the current tab:
  x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
  // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
  currentTab = currentTab + n;
  // if you have reached the end of the form... :
  if (currentTab >= x.length) {
    //...the form gets submitted:
    document.getElementById("Sheet1").submit();
    return false;
  }
  // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
  showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
  // This function deals with validation of the form fields
  var x, y, i, valid = true;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
  // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    // If a field is empty...
    if (y[i].value == "") {
      // add an "invalid" class to the field:
      y[i].className += " invalid";
      // and set the current valid status to false:
      valid = false;
    }
  }
  // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
  if (valid) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
  }
  return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
  // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
  var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  //... and adds the "active" class to the current step:
  x[n].className += " active";
}
```

And the complete html code-

```html
<main>
<form method="post" name="google-sheet" form id="Sheet1">


                <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
                <div class="tab"><div style="font-size: 30px;">From</div> <br><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Enter your Full Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="fullname"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Enter your address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="address"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Enter your state" oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="state"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Enter your District" oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="district"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Enter your Taluka" oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="taluka"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Enter your pincode" oninput="this.className = ''"
                name="pincode"></p><br>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="tab"><div style="font-size: 30px;">To</div><br><br>
                    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's Full Name" oninput="this.className = ''" name="name"></p><br>
                    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's address" oninput="this.className = ''" name="raddress"></p><br>
                    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's state" oninput="this.className = ''" name="rstate"></p><br>
                    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's District" oninput="this.className = ''" name="rdistrict"></p><br>
                    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's Taluka" oninput="this.className = ''" name="rtaluka"></p><br>
                    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's pincode" oninput="this.className = ''" name="rpincode"></p><br>
                </div>
                
                <div class="tab">Letter
                <p><input placeholder="Subject" oninput="this.className=''" name="subject"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Applicant" oninput="this.className=''" name="applicant"></p><br>
                <p><input placeholder="Type your letter here" oninput="this.className=''" name="letter"></p><br>
                <!-- <button style="height:52px;width:120px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" buttton type="submit"
                        id="submitBtn">Submit</button> -->
                
                <!--<textarea name="textarea" rows="25" cols="42" name="letter">Type your letter here...
                </textarea>-->
                <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
                </div>
                
                <div style="overflow:auto;">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <button style="height:52px;width:120px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                    <button style="height:50px;width:100px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" button type="button"
                    id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                    <!-- <button style="height:52px;width:120px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" buttton type="submit"id="submitBtn">Submit</button> -->
                        
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
                <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                <span class="step"></span>
                <span class="step"></span>
                <span class="step"></span>
                <span class="step"></span>
                </div>
                
        </form>
        <script src="form.js"></script>

        <script>
            const scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwn5fAoC5qFY5ZdkjLq27iJ8S0b9XY384KSs0TgijSru2XuCG4Ls81V2OUjBgY2wxJZ/exec'
            const form = document.forms['google-sheet']
        
            form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
                .then(response => alert("Thanks for Contacting us..! We Will Contact You Soon..."))
                .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
            })
        </script>
        </main>
```

Comment: Hm, `document.getElementById("nextBtn").type = 'submit';`

Comment: Sheez. I am looking for checkValidity and I find [this identical form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59618529/checkvalidity-and-reportvalidity-is-not-working-in-the-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my changes

I currently do not stop from going to next page if the fields are empty, but I will figure something out tomorrow

```js
const form = document.getElementById("Sheet1")
const prev = document.getElementById("prevBtn");
const next = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
const sub = document.getElementById("submitBtn");
const x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
const last = x.length - 1;
let currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
let allowSubmit = false;

form.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target
  if (!tgt.matches("button")) return; // not a button
  x[currentTab].hidden = true;
  if (tgt.id==="prevBtn") currentTab--;
  if (tgt.id==="nextBtn") currentTab++;
  if (currentTab<0) currentTab=0;
  if (currentTab>=last) currentTab=last;
  x[currentTab].hidden = false;
  prev.hidden = currentTab === 0;
  next.hidden = currentTab >= last;
  sub.hidden = currentTab !== last
  console.log(checkValidity)
 // if (currentTab !== last) e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form method="post" name="google-sheet" id="Sheet1">
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">
    <div style="font-size: 30px;">From</div> <br><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your Full Name" required name="fullname" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your address" required name="address" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your state" required name="state" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your District" required name="district" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your Taluka" required name="taluka" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter your pincode" required name="pincode" value=""></p><br>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" hidden>
    <div style="font-size: 30px;">To</div><br><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's Full Name" required name="name" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's address" required name="raddress" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's state" required name="rstate" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's District" required name="rdistrict" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's Taluka" required name="rtaluka" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Enter receiver's pincode" required name="rpincode" value=""></p><br>
  </div>
  <div class="tab" hidden>Letter
    <p><input placeholder="Subject" required name="subject" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Applicant" required name="applicant" value=""></p><br>
    <p><input placeholder="Type your letter here" required name="letter" value=""></p><br>
  </div>

  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button hidden style="height:52px;width:120px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" button type="submit" id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
      <button style="height:50px;width:100px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" button type="submit" id="nextBtn">Next</button>
      <button hidden style="height:52px;width:120px;color: red;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: bolder;font-size: 25px;" buttton type="submit" id="submitBtn">Submit</button>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @mplungjan , it worked but the next button's button type is changed  to submit button both at the last second and last step of the form.

Comment: Perhaps you need to move the counter n?

Comment: Would you please tell me how to do so, I am still learning it.

Comment: I cannot tell. You need to post more code

Comment: I have edited the question and posted the js code, would you please take a look. @mplungjan

Comment: You added MY code. Not a good idea. This is not needed `} else {
    document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
  }` for example

Comment: No, I removed it but still the next button's button type is changed to submit button both at the last second and last step of the form. Please help me with this @mplungjan

Comment: You have too much code. It can be reduced so it is less complicated. I have tried but cannot test it because I do not have your HTML either

Comment: Ok, I will add up my html

Comment: I am off the computer for today. Been behind a screen for 12 hours

Comment: Would you please take a look, I have added up my html

Comment: I am suck on validity. I made all fields required to use 3 submit buttons but they do not work the way I expected. However navigation is now SO MUCH simpler

Comment: I tried running the code but none of my input type's appear only the next, prev and submit appears, So, is it the issue of form validity.@mplungjan